# The program won't run, but there is no error

Tags: android, eclipse

I searched my problem and found someone else with a very similar one, but their solution is not the same. I wrote a code to do the simple task of multiplication depending on the button the user hits. The main.xml file and the accompanying java file are both error free, no warnings are even on the pages. Everything looks great, but when I try to run the program it pops up telling me that there are errors and to please fix them.  Nothing appears on the console nor in the LogCat. When I go to windows -> show view -> problems, it won't list anything pertaining to that program either.

My main.xml code is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="@string/number" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
    android:text="@string/1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="@string/3" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="@string/4" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
    android:text="@string/5" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button3"
    android:text="@string/6" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:text="@string/7" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
    android:text="@string/8" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button9"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button6"
    android:text="@string/9" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
     />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My Java:

```
package com.deitel.multiplicationtables;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.view.View;

//Implements the listener for an onclick event (implements View.onClickListener)
public abstract class Main extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{
// creates a button 
private Button bone, btwo, bthree, bfour, bfive, bsix, bseven, beight, bnine;

// Called when the activity is first created.
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

  //assigns the resource id of 1 - 9 to each button.
    bone = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btwo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    bthree = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    bfour = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    bfive = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
    bsix = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
    bseven = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
    beight = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
    bnine = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);

    //Adds the buttons to the onclicklistener
    bone.setOnClickListener(this);
    btwo.setOnClickListener(this);
    bthree.setOnClickListener(this);
    bfour.setOnClickListener(this);
    bfive.setOnClickListener(this);
    bsix.setOnClickListener(this);
    bseven.setOnClickListener(this);
    beight.setOnClickListener(this);
    bnine.setOnClickListener(this);

 }

 //creates a method (or action) for when the button is clicked.
 public void onclick(View view)
 {
    //Makes a variable for the entered number
    Double amount = 0.0;
    Double product = 0.0;
    Double variable = 0.0;

    // constants
    final double one = 1; 
    final double two = 2;
    final double three = 3;
    final double four = 4; 
    final double five = 5;
    final double six = 6;
    final double seven = 7; 
    final double eight = 8;
    final double nine = 9;

    if (view.getId() == R.id.button1)
    {
      variable = one;
    }
    if (view.getId() == R.id.button2)
    {
        variable = two;
    }
    if (view.getId()== R.id.button3)
    {
        variable = three;
    }

    if (view.getId() == R.id.button4)
    {
      variable = four;
    }
    if (view.getId() == R.id.button5)
    {
        variable = five;
    }
    if (view.getId()== R.id.button6)
    {
        variable = six;
    }

    if (view.getId() == R.id.button7)
    {
      variable = seven;
    }
    if (view.getId() == R.id.button8)
    {
        variable = eight;
    }
    if (view.getId()== R.id.button9)
    {
        variable = nine;
    }




    //creates an editext and assigns the resource id of the xml edittext.
    EditText number = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);



    //Receives the input from the edittext, converts it to a double (number).
    amount = Double.parseDouble(number.getText().toString());
    //Calculates the product
    product = variable * amount;


    //Creates a textview object, assigns the xml r.id, and then changes the text to
   report the amount.
     TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2); 
        t.setText("Your product is: " + product);

     }



}
```

Comment: Did you declare the activity in your AndroidManifest.xml file? If not, try that first. Otherwise, please post the logcat output when you try to run the program.

Comment: You should always post your LogCat.

Comment: If you're using eclipse take a look a the Problem View. What are the issues described there (Window->Show View->Problems)? Any output in Console view? Have you tried cleaning the project(Project->Clean...)?

Comment: Idid post about my LogCat, though. I posted that the LogCat remains blank. Nothing at all appears in it when I try to run the program.

Comment: Nothing pertaining to this program is in Problem View, but no I have not tried cleaning the project, I'll do that now. I think I declared the activity, but I'll check again.

Comment: I believe Eclipse declared my activity in the manifest for me, and cleaning didn't help. Thank you for the advice, though. I'll keep it in mind for later.

Answer (score 2):

```
public abstract class Main extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{
    ...
}
```

`abstract class`? Why? You will never be able to instanciate an abstract `Activity`!

Remove the `abstract` declaration and it will work fine. And make sure you have declared `Main` acivity at th application's manifest.

Comment: I tried removing abstract, but it tells me "The type Main must implement the inherited abstract method View.OnClickListener(View)"

Comment: Have you defined your Main activity as the LAUNCHER one? You must have some kind of feedback!

Comment: Yes:             <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

Comment: @LucianCat If you declare the class as implementing View.OnClickListener, then you need to provide the methods defined by that interface.  Strictly speaking, that's optional for the Activity, but if you want to respond to clicks, that's one way to accomplish it.

Comment: @yugi I know, I should have something, but that's what stumps me. I right click my program, I click run as android application, an error pops up, and then nothing. I've tried multiple times, but nothing appears in the console nor logcat, and anything in the Problems view pertains to other programs that I created in the past.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to check all of your multiplication logic, but the heart of your question is around why the button click is not working. You need to do two more things:

1. Instantiate a **separate** OnClickListener object to handle the clicks. The way you're doing it won't work and is going to cause headaches. It goes against the whole MVC nature of Android, which I won't get into here, but in short you're asking a Controller to do a View's job. Just trust me here.
2. Pay attention to case-sensitivity when typing method names.  Your method name is onclick(View v). The method name must be onClick(View v) (note the capital letter C). Java is a case-sensitive language, so you're method will never be invoked.

(Your Activity class cannot be declared as abstract as others have pointed out, but it sounds like you've fixed this.)

See my comments preceded by NOTE comments

Example:

```
//NOTE Main no longer implements View.OnClickListener
public class Main extends Activity {
// creates a button 
private Button bone, btwo, bthree, bfour, bfive, bsix, bseven, beight, bnine;

// Called when the activity is first created.
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

  //assigns the resource id of 1 - 9 to each button.
    bone = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btwo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    bthree = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    bfour = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    bfive = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
    bsix = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
    bseven = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
    beight = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
    bnine = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);

//NOTE seperate onClickListener()
OnClickListener oc = new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    //creates a method (or action) for when the button is clicked.
    public void onClick(View view) //NOTE the capital C in Click
    {
        //Makes a variable for the entered number
        Double amount = 0.0;
        Double product = 0.0;
        Double variable = 0.0;

        // constants
        final double one = 1; 
        final double two = 2;
        final double three = 3;
        final double four = 4; 
        final double five = 5;
        final double six = 6;
        final double seven = 7; 
        final double eight = 8;
        final double nine = 9;

        if (view.getId() == R.id.button1)
        {
            variable = one;
        }
        if (view.getId() == R.id.button2)
        {
            variable = two;
        }
        if (view.getId()== R.id.button3)
        {
            variable = three;
        }

        if (view.getId() == R.id.button4)
        {
            variable = four;
        }
        if (view.getId() == R.id.button5)
        {
            variable = five;
        }
        if (view.getId()== R.id.button6)
        {
            variable = six;
        }

        if (view.getId() == R.id.button7)
        {
            variable = seven;
        }
        if (view.getId() == R.id.button8)
        {
            variable = eight;
        }
        if (view.getId()== R.id.button9)
        {
            variable = nine;
    }

    }
};

//NOTE setting the seperate OnClickListener
//Adds the buttons to the onclicklistener
bone.setOnClickListener(oc);
btwo.setOnClickListener(oc);
bthree.setOnClickListener(oc);
bfour.setOnClickListener(oc);
bfive.setOnClickListener(oc);
bsix.setOnClickListener(oc);
bseven.setOnClickListener(oc);
beight.setOnClickListener(oc);
bnine.setOnClickListener(oc);

//...snip...
}
}
```